# How to set DocumentRoot in httpd.conf to windows environment variable

Tags: windows-7-x64, wampserver, httpd.conf, apache2.2

First I want to say thanks to community for all the answers I've found here in the past.  I'd like to set the DocumentRoot line in the http.conf file to the current windows user's dropbox folder.  I thought you could do it by doing something like...
DocumentRoot "C:/Users/${USERNAME}/Dropbox/"
&

but that isn't working.  Is there a way to set config files to Windows environment variables?

Comment: ${VAR} is for Linux , did you try %USERNAME% instead ?